# Firebase retrieved documents/collections are empty with no error

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firebase database contains 2 collections of name "collectionA" and "collectionB", and they both contain different documents. They both have rules to allow authenticated users to read and write (however I don't get permission erros anyway). The problem is when I get a reference to collectionA and B as such:

`var docRefA = db.collection("collectionA")`

`var docRefB = db.collection("collectionB")`

Collection A retrieves docs with its respective documents, but collection B returns empty docs. I can still write to collection B succesfully though, so I know the docRef isn't wrong. I'll attach an image of the actual collections in case there is any differences between the collections I'm not aware of:
[collection A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VktEW.png) - "users" collection would be collectionA and "store_exercises" would be B. The only difference I see is the documents in B are greyed out and italic, not sure what this could mean?

EDIT 1: This is how I generate/add items to collection A (I can see both write operations work, it's only reading):

```
val userMap = HashMap<String, String>()
    userMap["username"] = username
    userMap["email"] = email
                    db.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser!!.uid).set(userMap)
```

and collection B:

```
db.collection("store_exercises").document("whatever").collection("another_collection").document("name")
                .set(myObject)
```

EDIT 2: Image of contents of the two collections:
[contents of both collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1p8j.png)

Else, how can I debug a query? or test this scenario?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using for "collectionB".

Comment: There you go @AlexMamo , let me know if anything else helps

Comment: Show us also the fields of those documents.

Comment: See the attached picture in EDIT 2, the only difference is the documents in A have fields and another collection, whilst in in B the documents only contain other collections, not fields (the documents in those collections are however, not empty) @AlexMamo

Comment: Figured it out while comparing the pictures, thank anyway @AlexMamo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just figured that one out, if a document doesn't contain fields, and just collections (even if those collections are composed of non empty documents), then it will think its an "empty branch" and not display anything chained in there.

I only wanted 2 collections so I had to create a document to link them so I didn't add any fields, but unless there's some notation or something it seems like adding at least one field is a must for them to be read. All I did was add one field to the documents in collection B, and now they're not empty.